# Call a function multiple times and get a list of results in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a function `func f() -> Int` and I would like to call it `n: Int` times, and get the list of returned values.

In ruby, you would do `n.times.collect { f }`.

Does swift have a similar functional approach?

At the moment, I use the following handmade implementation:

```swift
extension Int {
  func collect<T>(f: () -> T) -> [T] {
    var l: [T] = []
    for _ in 0..<self {
      l.append(f())
    }
    return l
  }
}


// Usage
let myList = 42.collect { UIView(frame: self.bounds) }
```

Comment: Your implementation is good, but I’d change it to use `map` like in the answer below. Also, `guard self > 0 else { return [] }` is advised to prevent crashes.

Comment: Thanks for making me noticing 1...0 crash :o

Answer (score 5):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but you can use `Range`s with higher order functions.

Example:

```
// a range of 1 to 42
let range = (1...42) 
let views1 = range.map { _ in
    return UIView(frame: self.bounds)
}


// Shorthand
let views2 = (1...42).map { _ in UIView(frame: self.bounds) }
```